# Многоосновное и сложносоставное предложение?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

При проверке ученической работы учитель исправляет предложение "Я учился бы в кадетском корпусе, и когда в 1812 году началась бы Отечественная война, непременно принял бы участие в сражениях за судьбу Родины". Первая запятая поставлена учителем, дано следующее пояснение: " Многоосновное сложносоставное предложение, две основы, пропущена разделительная запятая перед "И".
Прокомментируйте, пожалуйста, данное пояснение. Может, я что-то забыла из курса русского языка? Разве правильно поставлена первая запятая? Что такое "многоосновное", "сложносоставное" предложение? Разве употребляются такие термины применительно к сложному предложению?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Единственно верный вариант расстановки запятых: «Я учился бы в кадетском корпусе и, когда в 1812 году началась бы Отечественная война, непременно принял бы участие в сражениях за судьбу Родины».

Запятая перед союзом *и* не нужна, потому что он соединяет однородные сказуемые (Я **учился бы** и **принял бы участие**), а вот перед союзом *когда* она необходима, так как придаточное предложение должно быть обособлено.

Либо учитель описáлся, либо допустил ошибку, либо вы неправильно его поняли.

Термины «многоосновное *и/или* сложносоставное предложение» выглядят нелепо. Навряд ли в хорошем учебнике были бы приняты такие названия для сложных предложений, ведь «сложносоставное», очевидно, избыточно, а «многоосновное» не общепринятое и трудно представить зачем нужное.

Если в вашем учебнике принята иная терминология, то вы можете смело выразить несогласие.

Comment: Это важно, учитель учит не принятой в учебнике терминологии. Он ее сам придумал или она существует? В Интернете не нашла ничего подобного.

Comment: @irina19 дополнил ответ.

Comment: Поняла, спасибо.

Comment: @irina19 Странная у Вас учительница, однако. Нет таких терминов в синтаксисе. Есть в словообразовании - сложносоставные слова: диван-кровать.

Comment: В дополнение к сказанному. Мне кажется лишним одно "бы": "...когда в 1812 году началась (бы?) Отечественная война". Война-то реально началась. @Людмила

Comment: М_Г , не поняла, к чему здесь   @Людмила

Comment: @Людмила Привлечь Ваше внимание (может, захотите прокомментировать)

Comment: Здесь же странная учительница, надо бы, конечно, поправить:Я учился бы в кадетском корпусе и в 1812 году, когда началась  Отечественная война, непременно принял бы участие в сражениях за судьбу Родины.